# Using a dos batch file, I want to save each Record Name and A (Host) Record from ipconfig /displaydns to a text file

Tags: batch, ipconfig

Using a dos batch file, in windows XP, I want to save each Record Name and A (Host) Record from ipconfig /displaydns to a text file.

Instead of

```
 www.netword.com
 ----------------------------------------
 Record Name . . . . . : www.netword.com
 Record Type . . . . . : 1
 Time To Live  . . . . : 586924
 Data Length . . . . . : 4
 Section . . . . . . . : Answer
 A (Host) Record . . . : 127.0.0.1
```

I want it to show like this

```
 ----------------------------------------
 Record Name . . . . . : www.netword.com
 A (Host) Record . . . : 127.0.0.1
```

I want it to do this for each site in the ipconfig listing and save the results to a text (*.txt) file.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. I now see your logic.

Answer (score 1):

Use `|` [*vertical line* to pipe](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) the `ipconfig` output into [`findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) as follows:

```
ipconfig /displaydns | findstr /C:"Record Name" /C:"A (Host) Record" /C:"----"
```

Use `>` [*greater than sign* to redirect all output to a text file](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) named e.g. `ipc.txt` (note parentheses!):

```
> ipc.txt (ipconfig /displaydns | findstr /C:"Record Name" /C:"A (Host) Record" /C:"----")
```

Comment: Thank you JosefZ.   
  
   I was trying to use ipconfig /[*] to clear the dns history on XP sp3.   
  
   I tried blocking sites with the host file, but that simply made them go local.  
  
   Something is trying to go to these (and other) sites.   
    
   Record Name . . . . . : www.ainews.com    
   Record Name . . . . . : ccas.clearchannel.com    
   Record Name . . . . . : ads.webcash.nl
   Record Name . . . . . : ads.vegas.com
   [etc.]
  
  Your code will help me in digging them out of whereever they originate and stopping them from returning.  

  Thank you JosefZ.

Comment: @UzuBlade I suspect you are on a wild goose chase... [see this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912).

Comment: I shall try to learn from that page.   Maybe it is better not to be seriously irritated against some program that is trying to do unauthorized stuff when forming a conversation.   I am reading your link.   Thanks for the help.   You are tolerant.   I shall try to not ask in XY problem format, when I better understand it.   Maybe "What have you tried" might not have been such a bad question to ask.